# filter dates from dataframe

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pandas

I need to remove all kinds of dates (`mm-dd-yy`, `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yy`, `dd-Mon-yyyy` etc) from a `.csv` file using pandas dataframe. Can the filter method be of any use?

```
for col in df.columns.values: 
  pd.filter(regex = '(([1-9]|1[012])[-/.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])(3‌​[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])(19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])[-/.](3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])[-/.]‌​(19|20)\d\d)')
```

E.g: If I have a `.csv` file with various columns with some data and dates like `10/12/2015`, `12/01/1995`, `2016-19-04`, `19th April,2016`, etc., the output file must contain no dates.

Data Sample

```
column1    column2     column3 
  data  4th April,2016  data 
4/20/2016 20-04-16    20.04.2016
  data      data      20-04-2016 
4-Apr-16    data      20/04/2016
```

as you can see I have various formats for dates here. I need to remove them all.

Comment: your attempt, please

Comment: for col in df.columns.values:
            pd.filter(regex = '(([1-9]|1[012])[-/.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])(3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])(19|20)\d\d)|((1[012]|0[1-9])[-/.](3[01]|2\d|1\d|0[1-9])[-/.](19|20)\d\d)')

Comment: but this throws AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Sorry but I am new to python and have only started exploring

Comment: Ok, can you add sample of dataframe (5-6 rows) and desired output? Other data are `string`, `float`, `int`?

Comment: @jezrael yes the other data is string.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use regex to filter out dates, but I find another way: pick up first row of your dataFrame (assuming there is no NaN in your df), initialize a `pandas.Timestamp` object with each value of the row. If success, the corresponding column contains date

```
time_columns = []
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        t = pandas.Timestamp(df.loc[0, col])
        time_columns.append(col)
    except Exception:
        pass
df = df.drop(time_columns, axis=1)
```

But I don't think this is a good solution. It's a little bit weird. Instead, I think you might analyze your original data first

Comment: But on entering a date in the format 12/12/2012 the following error is shown. ValueError: labels ['12/12/2012'] not contained in axis

Comment: @AnilaA can you show me your code and sample of your data?

Comment: I see your sample. So you mean you want to change every date into 'NaN'? or remove the whole column? or row?

Comment: I want to remove dates from the cells. The dates can appear between data also. For eg. Input : Today is 20-04-2016 and a Wednesday. Output : Today is and a Wednesday.

Comment: I see. Then my answer was wrong. What you need is df.replace() or df.applymap() with regex. I'll change my answer later

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have found a solution for 80% of my problem. Some more date formats need to be validated. Thank you for your suggestions and help everyone. :)   
def executeDateRemover(self):
    data = self.readCSV()    
    newData = data
    for column in newData:

 newData[column]= newData[column].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})', ' ', x))
    pass
self.writeCSV(newData)
```